# Run time error 1004 Application defined or object error, Hyperlink VBA

Tags: vba, excel

The script below runs through a sheet called "report auto" and finds a corresponding cell in another sheet with a matching ID. This is done using String compare. Then it writes a hyperlink in Report_Auto which links back to the corresponding data in sheet "Data". Now when I try to run the script I get error

> "Run time error 1004 Application defined or object error, Hyperlink
>   VBA".

```
Sub generatehyperlinks()
Dim i As Integer
Dim pointer As Integer
Dim choice As Integer

pointer = 1
choice = 0

Do While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report_Auto").Cells(pointer, 1) <> ""

For i = 1 To 7100
If InStr(1, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report_Auto").Cells(i, 2).Value, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(pointer, 4).Value, vbTextCompare) >= 1 Then
choice = i
End If
Next i

Report_Auto.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report_Auto").Cells(pointer, 1), Address:="", _
    SubAddress:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(choice, 1), TextToDisplay:="Test"

pointer = pointer + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Where is Report defined? Are you working in the same workbook at all times? Which line produces the error?

Comment: Choice cannot be zero as no 0 row in sheet. You will need to ensure it is always 1 or more. That is a likely culprit but not enough for me to post as an aswer at this point. And please use Long not Integer to avoid any risk of overflow.

Comment: @QHarr sorry fixed that should be Report_Auto

Comment: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report_Auto").Hyperlinks.Add .....etc

Comment: See my comment above

Comment: @QHarr that eliminated the error I was getting but now I have run-time error 5 Invalid Procedure call or argument.

Comment: So we need to check the hyperlink arguments

Comment: I suggest you remove the end ones to see if you  can narrow down the problem. Also, I think you attempted to bold the problem line which has now introduced ** into your code above.

Comment: The problem is the subaddress. See edit.

Answer (score 1):

1) Always use `Option Explicit` at the top of your code to check variable declarations and spelling

2) Use `Long` rather than `Integer` to avoid potential overflow, especially when working with rows in the sheet which can be larger than Integer can handle

3) Ensure `Choice` is > 0 as there is no row 0 in the sheet. `Pointer` also, but you start `Pointer` at 1.

4) The hyperlinks are added to the worksheet object so use:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report_Auto").Hyperlinks.Add
```

5) `SubAddress` must be string such as

```
SubAddress:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(2, 1).Address, TextToDisplay:="Test"
```

Comment: Did this answer prove to be lacking?